# Kivy: Can't add button from python code "AttrErr: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__"

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I know this question was asked multiple times but those solutions didnt help me, or i really dont get it.

I want to add numeric buttons with the help of python "for loop", but when i do it i get the following error:

"self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(Button(text="hi"))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'"

I am stuck here for a very long time.

Whenever i delete the button part in the 'GoodsView()' (python file) the porgram runs perfectly. So i could just type the numbers myself in "kv rule" but later i want to add labels which are generated by functions so i need to find a way now or later i will have more problems.

py:

```
class ActionBar(ActionBar):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen_one(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_two(Screen):
    pass


class GoodsView(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GoodsView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(10):
            self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(Button(text="hi"))


class Screen_three(Screen):
    pass


class RandApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("pcapp.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RandApp().run()
```

kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .65, .75, .85, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    ActionBar: ...
    Manager:
        id: sm
        Screen_one:
            ...
        Screen_two:
            ...
        Screen_three:
            ...
<Screen_one>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click1"
            size_hint: .2, .05
            pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .4}
            on_release:
                app.root.ids.sm.current  = 'screen2'
        Label:
            text: 'Hello!'
            pos_hint: {'x': -0.2, 'y': 0}

<Screen_two>:
    GoodsView:


<GoodsView>:
    id:gv
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    size_hint_x: .7
    size_hint_y: .7
    pos_hint: {'x': .15,'y': .15}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    GridLayout:
        id: GoodsContainer
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: '50dp'
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
```

Edit1
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'GoodsContainer'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/shokh/Desktop/PhytonSaves/Calculator.py", line 44, in <module>
     CalculatorApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/shokh/Desktop/PhytonSaves/Calculator.py", line 40, in build
     return Builder.load_file("pcapp.kv")
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 657, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\shokh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:/Users/shokh/Desktop/PhytonSaves/Calculator.py", line 31, in __init__
     self.ids.GoodsContainer.add_widget(Button(text="hi"))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: When posting a Python traceback, post the whole thing, not just the last message. The previous lines give information about the problem.

In this case, is `self.ids.GoodsContainer` None at the point you access it?

Comment: @inclement you probably  realised but i am new, im sorry. Though i have added the the whole traceback in 'Edit1'.

Comment: Sure enough the full traceback reveals a completely different error. Note that it says "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred". This second exception is less important than understanding the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the ids dictionary isn't yet populated during `__init__`, because all the other widgets haven't been created and added to one another yet.

Try doing something like

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

# ...and the following in your class

def __init__(self, *args **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.post_init, 0)

def post_init(self, dt):
    # your code goes here
```

This schedules your code to be run on the next frame, after everything is initialised.